# Relationship between trigonometric and hyperbolic sine

Tags: trigonometry

Why is the following identity true?

$$ \sin(ix) = i\sinh(x)$$

When I do the calculation, I get this:$$\sin(ix) = \frac{{e^{i(ix)}}-e^{-i(ix)}}{2i}=\frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{2i}=-\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2i}=-\left(\frac{\sinh(x)}{i}\right)$$

Comment: Remember $i^2=-1$ and thus $i=-1/i$

Comment: oops, I was using p on a problem, fixed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sin(ix) = \frac{{e^{i(ix)}}-e^{-i(ix)}}{2i}=\frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{2i}=-\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2i}=-\left(\frac{\operatorname{sinh}(x)}{i}\right)=i\operatorname{sinh}(x)$$ because $1/i=-i$

Comment: all you did was put " = isinh(x)" at the end of my equation

Comment: not at all ! marwalix used the fact that $-\frac 1i=i$ which finishes the proof.

Comment: I had hinted that in a comment to the question. By the way I also formatted the hyperbolic sine using \operatorname

Comment: @marwalix No need: the command \sinh already gives $\;\sinh x\;$ , and likewise \cosh x . +1

Comment: Wasn't sure that the LaTex add-on of SE has that. Not all have

Comment: Yes, I get whats going on now but shouldn't your comment be in your answer? I said why does a = b, when I get a=c?  Your answer is "c=b". Your comment was helpful and answered my question, but your answer doesn't add any new information.

Comment: Thought $i^2=-1$ was obvious but I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Another derivation:

$$\displaystyle \sin(ix) = ix - \frac {(ix)^3}{3!} + \frac {(ix)^5}{5!} - \frac {(ix)^7}{7!}+ \cdots$$

$$ = ix + \frac {ix^3} {3!} + \frac {ix^5}{5!} + \frac {ix^7}{7!} + \cdots $$

$$ = i \left({x + \frac {x^3}{3!} + \frac {x^5}{5!} + \frac {x^7}{7!} + \cdots }\right)= i \sinh x$$