# Showing $\sinh z=z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$, given $\sin z=z\prod_{n=1}^{ \infty}\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, hyperbolic-functions

How to show that

$$\sinh z=z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

using the well-know representation of sine as infinite product that is

$$\sin z=z\prod_{n=1}^{ \infty}\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

I have tried this problem for quite considerable amount of time. Indeed I also found a nice way to prove the former without using the latter. However I'm wondering if we can prove the result using the latter infinite product. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128746/relationship-between-trigonometric-and-hyperbolic-sine) that $\sinh(z) = \frac{1}{i}\sin(iz)$.

Comment: wait, how does it help here?

Comment: Replace $z$ with $iz$ everywhere in your product formula for $\sin z$ and see where you get.

Comment: Hmm, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you mean $\sin z=z\prod_{n=1}^{ \infty}\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$ for $z$ real or $z$ complex? In the latter case you got the answer below, in the former case you need to argue that $\sin z-z\prod_{n=1}^{ \infty}\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$ is **analytic** on the whole complex plane, that it vanishes on the real line implies it vanishes everywhere, so you can apply the answers below.

Comment: I meant for reals

Answer (score 3):

Since $\sinh z = \frac{1}{i}\sin(iz)$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\sinh z &= \frac{1}{i}\sin(iz) \\
&= \frac{1}{i}\times (iz)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1 - \frac{(iz)^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) \quad (\text{using the product formula for }\sin(\cdot))\\
&= z\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1 -\frac{-z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)\\
&= z\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1 +\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right), \\
\end{align*}
$$
as required.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, noting that $$\text{sinh}(z) = \frac{i}{1}\text{sin}(iz)$$
We have

$$\text{sinh}(z) = \frac{1}{i}\text{sin}(iz)= \frac{1}{i} (iz)\prod_{n=1}^{ \infty}\left(1 - \frac{(iz)^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) = z \prod_{n=1}^{ \infty}\left(1 +\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$